# Complex Integral of Absolute Value

Tags: complex-integration

I have a hard time understanding how one can take the following complex integral. $$\int |z|^2 \, dz.$$
Why is it not path independent.

Answer (score 3):

Absolute value is not an analytic function, so the integral will not be path independent.

Comment: But wouldn't the hypotheses of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and Cauchy's Theorem apply since the function is continuous, has an anti-derivative, and is differentiable on a domain containing the path?

Comment: It does not have an anti-derivative, and is not differentiable (in the complex sense).